# Do UK Academic Journals Generally Use Formatting Styles Based on APA, MLA, or Chicago?

Tags: writing-style, united-kingdom, online-publication

I'm working on an online formatting problem with a UK programmer who is not familiar with academic style requirements. The styling problem in one that is frequently encountered in APA and some Chicago-based style guides—both style guides that originated in America (U.S.). I'm wondering if UK journals also use styles based on these two American style guides.

Comment: I suspect that this is more a matter of academic discipline, not of country. In my experience (math/CS) a journal is providing the bibtex style file they want authors to use, and then you just use that. I only know of APA/Chicago due to questions by confused undergrads.

Comment: My formatting problem is for an online journal that published the lay theological research of a [PhD who was a bacteriologist and biochemist](https://worldviewpublications.org/outlook/pages/jdzwemer.php), so the formatting doubtless reflected his academic writing. It contains what APA and Chicago call [run-in headings](https://owl.excelsior.edu/citation-and-documentation/apa-style/apa-headings/) (levels 4 or 5), which are difficult to style online with [W3C](https://www.w3.org/standards/) styling tools. I was curious if this was a problem in the UK as well as the US.

Comment: Arno is right; country and citation style are not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've published in a mix of journals including some based in the UK.

I don't think I've encountered one yet that uses APA or Chicago or any other specific style guide; they all come up with their own, which may be loosely or closely based on some other guide (if one of them *has* used APA or Chicago it must not have been very notable at the time, though). I don't think it's possible to say "generally" for anything regarding citation format styles, particularly across fields.

Comment: Thank you. Good answer, and I appreciate that you are speaking from experience. The programmer is thinking about writing an article about the issue we are working on, and I got to thinking that maybe it's not an issue in the UK. But since, as you say, every journal has it's own rules (as is also true with most US-based journals), I suspect his article would be useful in at least some circumstances on his side of the Atlantic. And it would also be useful for UK academics who write for US-based journals.